# failed to pod install 'PayPal-iOS-SDK' , keep Installing CardIO (5.3.2)

Tags: ios, paypal, cocoapods

When I update PayPal-iOS-SDK with Cocoapods(1.0.1),
cmd logs below, and it has been installing CardIO for a long time.
Never changing the state.

> Analyzing dependencies
>
> Downloading dependencies
>
> Using AFNetworking (3.1.0)
>
> Installing CardIO (5.3.2)

podfile like this (Thanks @AMAN77)

> platform :ios, '7.0'
>
> inhibit_all_warnings!
>
> target 'IOS_CLIENT'
>
> pod 'SDWebImage', '3.8'
>
> pod 'MagicalRecord','2.3.0'
>
> pod 'Masonry','0.6.4'
>
> pod 'UMengAnalytics-NO-IDFA', '4.0.5'
>
> pod 'AFNetworking','3.1.0'
>
> pod 'MJRefresh','3.1.12'
>
> pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK'

I don't know how to figure it out. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Show us your pod file please.

Comment: i have post the pod file already, thanks @AMAN77

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want [the PayPal SDK without CardIO](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/358) (and it is over 100 Mb!), add the pod to your podfile as:

```
# Cocoapods v 1.1.1
pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK/Core'
```

I have tested it successfully on my current project.

Comment: Any effect using PayPal without CardIO? @AmitaiB

Comment: In Mock and Sandbox mode, no difference. Can't speak to Live/Production yet, but I would bet all the change and lint in my pockets that it would make no difference, save removing the CardIO feature.    [ CardIO is a nifty convenience bell/whistle, allowing you to scan in a credit card using the phone's camera (see their 30s demo video: https://youtu.be/7lg0nMH4NFk). They were acquired by PayPal in 2012 (https://techcrunch.com/2012/07/17/paypal-acquires-mobile-payments-startup-card-io/).]

Comment: Update: If CardIO is not loaded, then make sure that your `PayPalConfiguration` object has `acceptCreditCards` set to `false`, which hides the "Use Credit Card?" button in the view controller. That button will crash the app without the card.io package. @Yan

Comment: This is working. but I need the card payment. what I need to do to solve this problem?
Anyone solved this problem?

Comment: @kyl, can you unpack your particular problem?